# Azure Devops widget using azure-devops-extension-api to fetch all Pull requests by project only fetching one result

Tags: javascript, typescript, azure, azure-devops

I am trying to create a azure devops widget to pull all PRs associated with the project . The widget is working but only pulling one PR data and not all. Below is the widget code I am using

```
        VSS.require(["TFS/Dashboards/WidgetHelpers","TFS/VersionControl/GitRestClient"], 
        function (WidgetHelpers, TFS_Wit_WebApi) {
            WidgetHelpers.IncludeWidgetStyles();
            VSS.register("PRDuration", function () {                
            var projectId = VSS.getWebContext().project.id;

                var getQueryInfo = function (widgetSettings) {
                    // Get a WIT client to make REST calls to Azure DevOps Services                       
                   return TFS_Wit_WebApi.getClient().getPullRequestsByProject(projectId,"status: All ",null,0,100)
                        .then(function (prs) {
                            var $list = $('<ul>');
                            prs.forEach(function(pr) {                             
                            
                            //$list.append($('<li>').text("Project ID: " + projectId));
                            //$list.append($('<li>').text("Pull Request ID: " + pr.pullRequestId));
                            $list.append($('<li>').text("Pull Request title: " + pr.title));
                            $list.append($('<li>').text("Pull Request createdBy: " + pr.createdBy))
                            $list.append($('<li>').text("Pull Request creationDate: " + pr.creationDate));
                            $list.append($('<li>').text("Pull Request closedDate: " + pr.closedDate));
                            ;
                            //$list.append($('<li>').text("Query Name: " + query.name));
                            //$list.append($('<li>').text("Created By: " + (query.createdBy ? query.createdBy.displayName: "<unknown>") ));
                            })

                            // Append the list to the query-info-container
                            var $container = $('#query-info-container');
                            $container.empty();
                            $container.append($list);

                            // Use the widget helper and return success as Widget Status
                            return WidgetHelpers.WidgetStatusHelper.Success();
                        }, function (error) {
                            // Use the widget helper and return failure as Widget Status
                            return WidgetHelpers.WidgetStatusHelper.Failure(error.message);
                        });
                }

                return {
                    load: function (widgetSettings) {
                        // Set your title
                        var $title = $('h2.title');
                        $title.text('Hello World');

                        return getQueryInfo(widgetSettings);
                    }
                }
            });
        VSS.notifyLoadSucceeded();
    });
```

When I used this widget it seems to be making below API call and fetching just one result :
https://dev.azure.com/orgname/projectId/_apis/git/pullRequests?searchCriteria=status:All&api-version=6.0

If I am changing the api URL as below then I get all the results :
https://dev.azure.com/orgname/projectId/_apis/git/pullRequests?searchCriteria.status=All&api-version=6.0

Is there a way I can fix this in search criteria of function getPullRequestsByProject to get all results?

Comment: Have you considered this?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull-requests/get-pull-requests-by-project?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0

Comment: I have read that article , the iss is when using the library that I have mentioned ...as its translating api url differently

Comment: Have you checked this? [Is the Azure DevOps Rest Api returning the correct number of pullrequests?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67202609)

Comment: The searchcriteria for the function in azure-devops-extension-api is required. I cannot skit it neither I can directly use the api URL in widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to give search criteria in below format  and it worked:

```
var search_criteria = {"status": "All"}                  
                   return TFS_Wit_WebApi.getClient().getPullRequestsByProject(projectId,search_criteria)
```

This translates the URL to :
[https://dev.azure.com/org/projectId/_apis/git/pullRequests?searchCriteria[status]=All&api-version=6.0](https://dev.azure.com/org/projectId/_apis/git/pullRequests?searchCriteria%5Bstatus%5D=All&api-version=6.0)